# How to access child property in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

topmenu/script.js

```
module.exports = {
    components: {
        'topmenuSearch': require('vue').extend(require('./topmenu-search/component.vue'))
    }
}
```

/topmenu/template.html

```
<div class="search-overlay" v-if="topmenuSearch.searching"></div>
```

/topmenu/topmenu-search/script.js

```
module.exports = {
    data: function(){
        return {
            results: [],
            searchValue: '',
            searching: false
        }
    }
}
```

In console I get

```
build.js:3008 [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "topmenuSearch.searching": TypeError: Cannot read property 'searching' of undefined (found in component: <topmenu>)
```

How can I access the topmenuSearch child so I can do this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Vueify? I'm a bit confused by how you are organizing your files here. https://github.com/vuejs/vueify

What we need to see is your templates.  It looks like you have a `topmenu` component and a `topmenu-search` component, so the template for `topmenu` should look something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <topmenu-search></topmenu-search>
  </div>
</template>
```

Just because you declare the component doesn't mean it exists.  Adding it to your template creates the element.  Then you can use `v-ref` to access it's data inside `topmenu`:

```
<topmenu-search v-ref:search></topmenu-search>
<div class="search-overlay" v-if="$refs.search.searching"></div>
```